# Confusion with libxmp in python and setting properties

Tags: python

I am rather new to using libxmp, but my goal is to automate cleaning up photographers' captions so our news media database gets clean information and people can locate the photos. I am only interested in three properties in the metadata: title, creator and description. My code reads and edits them easily, assuming that they exist. If a property doesn't exist, I should be able to create it and set a value, but that's where I'm stumbling. Usually the creator and description exist, but the title will not, and it's needed to make sure non-technical people can find the photos easily. The XMP Toolkit docs say set_property should create any property that doesn't exist and set its value, but it errors out every time. I am also trying the "append_array_item", but that's a roadblock too. Here's my code:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from libxmp.utils import file_to_dict
from libxmp import XMPFiles, consts
import os, glob

redText = '\033[31m'
greenText = '\033[32m'
normalText = '\033[39m'

#----------------------------------------------
class Xmp():
    def __init__(self, filepath):
        self.filepath = filepath
        self.openXmp()

    # OPEN XMP DATA FOR WRITING
    def openXmp(self):
        try:
            self.xmpfile = XMPFiles(file_path=self.filepath, open_forupdate=True)
            self.xmp = self.xmpfile.get_xmp()
            self.printAsNormalText('Open file {0}.'.format(filepath))
            return self.xmp
        except:
            return None

    # CLOSE XMP FILE
    def closeXmp(self):
        self.xmpfile.close_file()
        self.printAsNormalText('Close file.')

    # WRITE BACK ANY UPDATES
    def updateXmp(self):
        if self.xmpfile.can_put_xmp(self.xmp):
            self.xmpfile.put_xmp(self.xmp)
            self.printAsNormalText('Updated file.')
        else:
            self.printAsErrorText('ERROR: Update')

    def printAsNormalText(self, msg):
        print(greenText + msg + normalText)

    def printAsErrorText(self, msg):
        print(redText + msg + normalText)
        

    # GET TITLE
    def getTitle(self):
        return self.getProperty('title[1]')

    # GET CREATOR
    def getCreator(self):
        return self.getProperty('creator[1]')

    # GET DESCRIPTION
    def getDescription(self):
        return self.getProperty('description[1]')

    # GET NAMED PROPERTY, IF IT EXISTS
    def getProperty(self, prop):
        if self.xmp.does_property_exist(consts.XMP_NS_DC, prop):
            return self.xmp.get_property(consts.XMP_NS_DC, prop)
        else:            
            return None
        
    # SET TITLE
    def setTitle(self, newTitle):
        return self.setProperty('title[1]', newTitle)

    # SET CREATOR
    def setCreator(self, newCreator):
        return self.setProperty('creator[1]', newCreator)

    # SET DESCRIPTION
    def setDescription(self, newDescription):
        return self.setProperty('description[1]', newDescription)

    # SET NAMED PROPERTY, OR CREATE IT IF IT DOESN'T EXIST
    def setProperty(self, prop, vl):
        if self.xmp.does_property_exist(consts.XMP_NS_DC, prop):
            self.xmp.set_property(consts.XMP_NS_DC, prop, vl)
            self.printAsNormalText('Set "{0}" to "{1}"'.format(prop, vl))
        else:
            try:
                self.xmp.append_array_item(consts.XMP_NS_DC, prop, vl, {'prop_array_is_ordered': True, 'prop_value_is_array': True})
            except:
                self.printAsErrorText('ERROR: Unable to set "{0}" field to "{1}".'.format(prop, vl))

#----------------------------------------------


sourceDir = '/Users/me/Desktop/testFolder'
os.chdir(sourceDir)
filelist = glob.glob('*.jpg')

for thisfile in filelist:
    r = Xmp(os.path.join(sourceDir, thisfile))

    r.setTitle('Our City Christmas Parade')
    r.setCreator('Photo Guy / For Our Paper')
    print('TITLE: ' + str(r.getTitle()))
    print('CREATOR: ' + str(r.getCreator()))
    print('DESCRIPTION: ' + str(r.getDescription()))
    print()
    r.updateXmp()
    r.closeXmp()
```

Any thoughts are appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code works to set the properties no matter what exists there. It does it by first deleting the property then adding the value provided.

From your question is not clear if this is the desired workflow, as you mention arrays. Check code in function setProperty for a comment regarding that.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from libxmp.utils import file_to_dict
from libxmp import XMPFiles, consts
import os, glob

redText = '\033[31m'
greenText = '\033[32m'
normalText = '\033[39m'

#----------------------------------------------
class Xmp():
    def __init__(self, filepath):
        self.filepath = filepath
        self.openXmp()

    # OPEN XMP DATA FOR WRITING
    def openXmp(self):
        try:
            self.xmpfile = XMPFiles(file_path=self.filepath, open_forupdate=True)
            self.xmp = self.xmpfile.get_xmp()
            self.printAsNormalText('Open file {0}.'.format(filepath))
            return self.xmp
        except:
            return None

    # CLOSE XMP FILE
    def closeXmp(self):
        self.xmpfile.close_file()
        self.printAsNormalText('Close file.')

    # WRITE BACK ANY UPDATES
    def updateXmp(self):
        if self.xmpfile.can_put_xmp(self.xmp):
            self.xmpfile.put_xmp(self.xmp)
            self.printAsNormalText('Updated file.')
        else:
            self.printAsErrorText('ERROR: Update')

    def printAsNormalText(self, msg):
        print(greenText + msg + normalText)

    def printAsErrorText(self, msg):
        print(redText + msg + normalText)


    # GET TITLE
    def getTitle(self):
        return self.getProperty('title[1]')

    # GET CREATOR
    def getCreator(self):
        return self.getProperty('creator[1]')

    # GET DESCRIPTION
    def getDescription(self):
        return self.getProperty('description[1]')

    # GET NAMED PROPERTY, IF IT EXISTS
    def getProperty(self, prop):
        if self.xmp.does_property_exist(consts.XMP_NS_DC, prop):
            return self.xmp.get_property(consts.XMP_NS_DC, prop)
        else:
            return None

    # SET TITLE
    def setTitle(self, newTitle):
        return self.setProperty('title', newTitle)

    # SET CREATOR
    def setCreator(self, newCreator):
        return self.setProperty('creator', newCreator)

    # SET DESCRIPTION
    def setDescription(self, newDescription):
        return self.setProperty('description', newDescription)

    # SET NAMED PROPERTY, OR CREATE IT IF IT DOESN'T EXIST
    def setProperty(self, prop, vl):
        self.xmp.delete_property(consts.XMP_NS_DC, prop)
        self.xmp.set_property(consts.XMP_NS_DC, prop, vl)
        
        # if you would like an array you could use, code below, instead of
        # set_property but for me worked only for creator not for other tags
        #
        # self.xmp.append_array_item(consts.XMP_NS_DC, prop, vl, {'prop_value_is_array':True})

        self.printAsNormalText('Set "{0}" to "{1}"'.format(prop, vl))

#----------------------------------------------


sourceDir = '.'
os.chdir(sourceDir)
filelist = glob.glob('*.jpg')

for thisfile in filelist:
    r = Xmp(os.path.join(sourceDir, thisfile))

    r.setTitle('Our City Christmas Parade')
    r.setCreator('Photo Guy / For Our Paper')
    r.setDescription('some description')
    print('TITLE: ' + str(r.getTitle()))
    print('CREATOR: ' + str(r.getCreator()))
    print('DESCRIPTION: ' + str(r.getDescription()))
    print()
    r.updateXmp()
    r.closeXmp()
```

Comment: It looks like the field names may have been the problem. I got those names ("title[1]", "creator[1]" and "description[1]") just from experimenting, but the default names as you listed appear to work. Thanks so much!